# Why is my button freezing and not recognizing any clicks?

Tags: java, android

I'm making a multiple choice game. You have 4 radioButtons and one button to go through them. When the time has run out, you will see the answers and after that you click the button to continue to the next question. The problem is that after the count down reached zero, you can't click the button anymore to continue. I tried to change the text of the question when you click the button to see wheter its still reacting and recognizing the clicks, but nothings happening at all. You can see the Methods for example in the on create method, where I'm setting a listener to my button and starting the countdown, or the actual time method after that big chunk full of objects (UpdateCountDownText and StartCountdown). I don't know wheter the problem lies in the time method itself, or if I just used them wrong. I'm sorry its so messy.

Where is the problem? I appreciate your help!

Heres my Code:

```
public class QuizActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ImageView mImageView;
TextView mTextView;
TextView mAnswer;
TextView score;
TextView countDown;
RadioGroup radioGroup;
RadioButton opt1;
RadioButton opt2;
RadioButton opt3;
RadioButton opt4;
Button check;

boolean answered = false;


public static final long COUNTDOWN_IN_MILLISECODS = 30000;
public CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
public long timeLeftInMilliseconds;

private ColorStateList textColorDefaultCd;
private ColorStateList textColorDefaultRb;

int scoreNumber = 0;
int questionNumber = 0;
int questionNumberTotal = 9;
int arrayNumber = -1;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);

    mImageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    mTextView = findViewById(R.id.tvQ);
    mAnswer = findViewById(R.id.tvA);
    score = findViewById(R.id.tvScore);
    countDown = findViewById(R.id.tvCd);
    opt1 = findViewById(R.id.rb1);
    opt2 = findViewById(R.id.rb2);
    opt3 = findViewById(R.id.rb3);
    opt4 = findViewById(R.id.rb4);
    check = findViewById(R.id.btnCheck);
    radioGroup = findViewById(R.id.rG);

    textColorDefaultRb = opt1.getTextColors();

    textColorDefaultCd = countDown.getTextColors();

    shuffleQuestions();
    ShowNewQuestion();
    StartCountDown();

    check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            check.setText("Bestätigen");
            if (!answered) {
                if (opt1.isChecked() || opt2.isChecked() || opt3.isChecked() || opt4.isChecked()) {
                    CheckAnswer();
                    countDownTimer.cancel();
                    answered = true;
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Wählen Sie eine Antwort aus", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } else if (answered) {
                ShowNewQuestion();
                StartCountDown();
                answered = false;
            }
        }

    });
}


Objects q01 = new Objects(R.drawable.blauwahl, "Das Herz eines Blauwals ist ungefähr so groß wie...", "ein VW-Käfer", "Angela Merkels Privatjet", "ein VW-Käfer", "eine Vespa", "eine Wassermelone");
Objects q02 = new Objects(R.drawable.simbabwe, "Der südafrikanische Staat Simbabwe wurde 1980 unabhängig. Wie hieß das Land früher? ", "Rhodesien", "Botswana", "Rhodesien", "Südafrika", "Botsuana");
Objects q03 = new Objects(R.drawable.sonnenkoenig, " Der französische Sonnenkönig Ludwig XIV. herrschte lange Jahre über Frankreich. Wie viele? ", "72", "22", "52", "62", "72");
Objects q04 = new Objects(R.drawable.tempelberg, "Der Tempelberg in Jerusalem ist rund 144.000 Quadratmeter groß und beladen mit Mythen. Wer soll hier den ersten Mord der Menschheit begangen haben?", "Kain", "David", "Kain", "Herodes", "Joseph");
Objects q05 = new Objects(R.drawable.frauenkirche, "In welchem Jahr des Zweiten Weltkrieges wurde die Dresdener Frauenkirche zerstört? ", "1945", "1943", "1944", "1945", "1939");
Objects q06 = new Objects(R.drawable.kueste, "Welches dieser europäischen Länder hat die längste Küste?", "Griechenland", "Italien", "Griechenland", "Frankreich", "Türkei");
Objects q07 = new Objects(R.drawable.umriss, "Der Umriss welches inselreichen Landes ist hier zu sehen?", "Dänemark", "Dänemark", "Philippinen", "Kroatien", "Griechenland");
Objects q08 = new Objects(R.drawable.blitz, "Woran liegt es, dass man den Donner bei manchen Blitzen erst viel später hört als bei anderen?", "An der unterschiedlichen Entfernung der Blitze", "An der unterschiedlichen Entfernung der Blitze", "An der Stärke der elektrischen Entladungen", "An der Dichte des Regens", "An den heftigen Windböen");
Objects q09 = new Objects(R.drawable.biathlon, "Aus welchen beiden Disziplinen setzt sich ein Biathlon zuammen?", "Sportschießen und Skilanglauf", "Sportschießen und Skilanglauf", " Skispringen und Skilanglauf ", " Skilanglauf und Abfahrtslauf ", "Abfahrtslauf und Skispringen ");
Objects q10 = new Objects(R.drawable.licht, "In welcher physikalischen Einheit wird die Lichtstärke gemessen?", "Candela", "Joule", "Lumen", "Lux", "Candela");
Objects q11 = new Objects(R.drawable.sonne, "Welcher Planet unseres Sonnensystems ist am weitesten von der Sonne entfernt?", "Neptun", "Uranus", "Jupiter", "Neptun", "Saturn");

Objects[] objectsArray = new Objects[]{
        q01, q02, q03, q04, q05, q06, q07, q08, q09, q10, q11
};

public void shuffleQuestions() {

    Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(objectsArray));
}

public void ShowNewQuestion() {
    if (questionNumber < questionNumberTotal) {

        opt1.setTextColor(textColorDefaultRb);
        opt2.setTextColor(textColorDefaultRb);
        opt3.setTextColor(textColorDefaultRb);
        opt4.setTextColor(textColorDefaultRb);

        radioGroup.clearCheck();
        answered = false;

        arrayNumber++;

        mTextView.setText(objectsArray[arrayNumber].getmQuestion());
        mImageView.setImageResource(objectsArray[arrayNumber].getmImages());
        opt1.setText(objectsArray[arrayNumber].getmOption1());
        opt2.setText(objectsArray[arrayNumber].getmOption2());
        opt3.setText(objectsArray[arrayNumber].getmOption3());
        opt4.setText(objectsArray[arrayNumber].getmOption4());
        mAnswer.setText(objectsArray[arrayNumber].getmAnswer());

        timeLeftInMilliseconds = COUNTDOWN_IN_MILLISECODS;
    } else {
        FinishQuiz();
    }
}

void StartCountDown() {
    countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(timeLeftInMilliseconds, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            timeLeftInMilliseconds = millisUntilFinished;
            UpdateCountdownText();


        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            timeLeftInMilliseconds = 0;
            UpdateCountdownText();
            CheckAnswer();
            StartCountDown();

        }
    }.start();
}

public void ShowSolution() {
    answered = false;
    countDownTimer.cancel();
    if (opt1.getText().equals(mAnswer.getText())) {
        mTextView.setText("Nummer 1 ist richtig.");
        opt1.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        opt2.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        opt3.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        opt4.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    } else if (opt2.getText().equals(mAnswer.getText())) {

        mTextView.setText("Nummer 2 ist richtig.");
        opt1.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        opt2.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        opt3.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        opt4.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    } else if (opt3.getText().equals(mAnswer.getText())) {

        mTextView.setText("Nummer 3 ist richtig.");
        opt1.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        opt2.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        opt3.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        opt4.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    } else if (opt4.getText().equals(mAnswer.getText())) {

        mTextView.setText("Nummer 4 ist richtig.");
        opt1.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        opt2.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        opt3.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        opt4.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
    }

    if (questionNumber < questionNumberTotal) {
        check.setText("Weiter");
        StartCountDown();
    } else {
        check.setText("Ergebnis");
        FinishQuiz();
    }
}

public void CheckAnswer() {
    answered = true;

    countDownTimer.cancel();

    if (opt1.isChecked()) {
        if (opt1.getText().equals(mAnswer.getText())) {
            scoreNumber++;
            questionNumber++;
            UpdateScore();
            countDownTimer.cancel();

        }

    } else if (opt2.isChecked()) {
        if (opt2.getText().equals(mAnswer.getText())) {
            scoreNumber++;
            questionNumber++;
            UpdateScore();
            countDownTimer.cancel();

        }

    }
    if (opt3.isChecked()) {
        if (opt3.getText().equals(mAnswer.getText())) {
            scoreNumber++;
            questionNumber++;
            UpdateScore();
            countDownTimer.cancel();

        }

    }
    else if (opt4.isChecked()) {
        if (opt4.getText().equals(mAnswer.getText())) {
            scoreNumber++;
            questionNumber++;
            UpdateScore();
            countDownTimer.cancel();

        } else {
            questionNumber++;
            countDownTimer.cancel();
        }
    }

    ShowSolution();
}

void UpdateCountdownText() {
    int minutes = (int) (timeLeftInMilliseconds / 1000) / 60;
    int seconds = (int) (timeLeftInMilliseconds / 1000) % 60;

    String timeFormatted = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds);

    countDown.setText(timeFormatted);

    if (timeLeftInMilliseconds < 10000) {
        countDown.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    } else {
        countDown.setTextColor(textColorDefaultCd);
    }

    if (countDown.getText().equals("00:00")) {
        CheckAnswer();
        answered = true;
        check.setClickable(true);

    }

    };

    public void FinishQuiz () {

        Intent i = new Intent(QuizActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("finalScore", scoreNumber + 1);
        i.putExtras(bundle);
        QuizActivity.this.finish();
        startActivity(i);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy () {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (countDownTimer != null) {
            countDownTimer.cancel();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Why are you starting a new countdown when the current one finishes?

Comment: you are in a loop or in other words in a recursion in your onFinish function.

Comment: Not exactly a "recursion" in the strictest sense, but you are calling `new CountDownTimer()` while `timeLeftInMilliseconds` is 0.

Comment: I fixed it, its working fine now. Thank you so much!